# How is safe args in navigation component type safe (Android)?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-bundle, android-safe-args

In a normal fragment  transaction  we would pass data as:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Isn't this type safe too?
So what does it mean when we say that safe args are type safe?
What exactly does type safety mean when we say that safe args are type safe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you provided the regular form of passing arguments between fragments. This is type safe because `Bundle` class provide API to put and get data of different types. It means that you will not encounter `ClassCastException` using it (see detailed explanation below)

> So what does it mean when we say that safe args are type safe?

I presume you're talking about [**Safe args**](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args), which is a **Gradle plugin for Android** that provides a type-safe and easy-to-use mechanism for passing data between destinations **in the Android Navigation component.**

With Safe Args, you define the arguments for each destination in an XML file, and the plugin generates a strongly-typed class for each destination that contains accessor methods for each argument. These classes help to ensure that the arguments are of the correct type and prevent runtime errors caused by incorrect argument values. That makes this way of passing **type safe** and you can use it when you're using Android [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).

So you can define your fragments like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/destination_fragment"
    android:name="packageName.DestinationFragment">

    <argument
        android:name="firstArg"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="0" />

    <argument
        android:name="secondArg"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="" />

</fragment>
```

And start this fragment, passing arguments with Safe Args:

```
val action = FragmentDirections.actionSourceFragmentToDestinationFragment(firstArg = 12345, secondArg = "Hello World!")
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

**Update**

When you use the standard way of passing objects between fragments, it is not being checked on the compile time. So for instance, if you put `Int` value in a `Bundle` and try to get a `String` with a same key it will **return the default value**.

For example the value of `value` variable will be **null** in the example below:

```
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putInt("key", 1)
    }
    
    val value = bundle.getString("key")
    
    println(value) // null!
```

You can see why it happens in a `BaseBundle.getString()` method:

```
@Nullable
public String getString(@Nullable String key) { // key = "hey"
    unparcel();
    final Object o = mMap.get(key); // Here we got Integer = 1
    try {
        return (String) o; // Trying to cast Integer to String
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        typeWarning(key, o, "String", e);
        return null; // ClassCastException was caught => return null!
    }
}
```

Comment: So with Safe args, if we pass argument of incorrect type - it gets detected at compile time. But with bundle, wrong argument type does NOT get detected at compile time?

Comment: If bundle too is type safe - what is the advantage of using Safe args?

Comment: That is correct, I tried to explain in more details, check my updated answer please.

Comment: Although the question is answered correctly, I also post some posibility to use type safe Bundle below, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035914/1573348

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to type safe `Bundle`, I recently build a tool to achieve that.

Leverage on some Kotlin feature (value class, extension function, etc), we can easily use `Bundle` in a much safer way.

Example usage:

```
val textKey = StringKey("SomeStringKey")
val intKey = IntKey("SomeIntKey")
val bundle = Bundle()

bundle.put(textKey, "Some text")   // only String value is acceptable
bundle.put(intKey, 12345)          // only Int value is acceptable

val text = bundle.get(textKey, "") // guarantee result to be a String  
val int = bundle.get(intKey, -1)   // guarantee result to be an Int
```

The concept is we associate type info in the key string like `StringKey`, `IntKey` where it's a value class in Kotlin will compile back to `String` in the end but able to provide type information at build time.
And the extension function `get` and `set` will check these info to ensure everything is matched.

github link : https://github.com/Jintin/TypedBundle